# Variable og: tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags, meta, lint

Hello and thanks for checking out my question.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myurl.com/images/test.png"/>
```

I have an application that is intended to service multiple "campaigns", each having its own graphic and description I would like to show when someone likes the page.  I can update the meta tags all I want but FB will still only use the most recently scraped data (from the nightly scrape or from the linter).

I read that I might be able to cURL to the linter to have it pull the new data right before the like is sent, but what happens when I am servicing hundreds+ of people and multiple campaigns?

Is there any way around this?  I have not found any solid solutions after several hours of searching.

tl;dr
I want my posted likes to respect the current meta tags and ignore or update the FB cache for that data.

Comment: Can you just give each campaign a different URL parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each object / page needs its own URL, even if those URLs are handled by the same code -using a query string parameter in the URL to identify different objects is the most common way to achieve this, with server-side URL rewriting being another